# Incorrect Form validaton when using a proper SSL certificate

Tags: forms, validation, ssl, joomla, recaptcha

when I use a proper SSL Certificate on my Web-Site I get bugs in joomla which don't appear if using an unknown certificate of http:

1. When logging in with wrong credentials, I get to the error page 500 instead of validation and instead of the message "Username or password are wrong ..." faded in.
2. When registering and the wrong text in ReCaptcha is tipped instead of validation the data in all the fields is deleted and no message about wrong captcha is faded in.

What am I doing wrong when using the proper SSL-Certificate?

Note to ReCaptcha:
In K2 I put the script source metioned [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/tips).

Putting

```
RewriteCond .*(/component/users/?view=login) off
```

at the end of my .htaccess didn't help.

---

Technical data, which may be relevant:

SSL-Certificate: GeoTrust RapidSSL

CMS: Joomla! 2.5.9 Stable

Login-Form: Standard-Module of Joomla

Register-Form: Authentication-Plugin of Joomla + K2 2.6.2

---

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Might not be an issue for you, but you do realise that your K2 extensions is 3 versions out of date.

Comment: did you enable ssl from adminside ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. It wasn't an SSL issue.

These paths in *configuration.php* were not correct at the root and I've overlooked it :(

```
public $log_path = '/SERVER_PATH/JOOMLA_INSTALLATION/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/SERVER_PATH/JOOMLA_INSTALLATION/tmp';
```

So when you log on with wrong credentials or type a wrong ReCaptcha text, joomla tries to create the directories mentioned above. If joomla fails to do it (and it was the case), instead of validation by login form and ReCaptcha you get the strange behavior, described in my previous post.

@Lodder: I'll update my K2 next time

@Jobin Jose: Yes, I activated SSL adminside.